# Determining which fields and connections are returned in a FB.api query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I query Facebook via FB.api with the following:

```
me/events
```

A JSON event array in the returned JSON object has information for the fields "name", "start_tile", "end_time", "location", "id", and "rsvp_status". I know I can obtain information on additional fields and connections (such as the "picture" connection or the "owner" field) by parsing the "id" field and querying the individual event directly but is there a way to request this information in the initial query so I can avoid the extra FB.api calls?

```
{
  "name": "Example Name", 
  "start_time": "2012-05-04T22:00:00", 
  "end_time": "2012-05-05T01:00:00", 
  "location": "Example Location", 
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx", 
  "rsvp_status": "attending"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

> **Introspection**
>
> The Graph API supports introspection of objects, which enables you to
>   see all of the connections an object has without knowing its type
>   ahead of time. To get this information, add metadata=1 to the object
>   URL, and the resulting JSON will include a metadata property that
>   lists all the supported connections for the given object. For example,
>   you can see all the connections for the Developer Garage event above
>   by fetching https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435?metadata=1. That
>   outputs:

```
{
   "name": "Facebook Developer Garage Austin - SXSW Edition",
   "metadata": {
      "connections": {
         "feed": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/feed",
         "picture": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/picture",
         "invited": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/invited",
         "attending": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/attending",
         "maybe": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/maybe",
         "noreply": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/noreply",
         "declined": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/declined"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The answer you gave initially also worked, which was to add the desired fields after the query (e.x. me/events?&fields=owner,picture,location)